# Easy way to get SVN repository URL for ant build

Tags: svn

I'm in the sad process of migrating a Mercurial repository to Subversion. Our ant build grabbed the version of the working copy and stuck it in the build product using `hg id -i`, for purposes of traceability. This global ID is all you need to know to track down the version that was built.

Of course, it's not that easy with SVN. I know how to get the version of the working copy (or, *ahem*, range of versions in the WC) using `svnversion`, but that alone doesn't tell you the full story: you need to know which branch or tag you're on.

Is there an easy way to grab the repository URL corresponding to a WC path? What I want is the 'URL' line that's returned from `svn info`, but I really don't want to parse multi-line output to get it. There *has* to be an easy way to get just that information back.

Doesn't there?

I miss my DVCS. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the command line it looks like you're pretty much stuck parsing svn info. However you can use the svn ant tasks to help you out http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant/svntask.html#info. This will set a bunch of properties one of which is your repo url, I suspect it will be repourl but that isn't super well documented, it might be url.

Comment: Cheers! I'd looked at those tasks before, and after they didn't help me do what I wanted to do at the time, I promptly forgot about them.